# I have written a function to remove spaces from a sentence but its only taking chars before the space & not considering the entire sentance

Tags: c++, string, trim

I have written a function to remove spaces from a sentence but its only taking chars before the space & not considering the entire sentence. 
if I run this Out put is

```
Enter the string with space/ tab to trim
IamDoing very fine
Length of the String is : 8
IamDoing
```

I what changes I need to do get "IamDoingveryfine"
Please help, Code is as follows..."

```
void removeSpace(const string &str)
{
    string tempStr;
    string p_str = str;
    int l_length = p_str.length();
    cout<<"Length of the String is : "<<l_length<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<l_length; i++)
    {
        if(p_str[i] != ' ' || p_str[i] != '\t')
        {
            tempStr +=p_str[i]; //to add chars into tempstr
        }
    }
    cout<<tempStr<<'\n';
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Please can you post the code where you read in the string, as you should probably be doing `std::getline()` instead of `std::cin >>` to read in. And your `||` should be an `&&`.

Comment: All characters are different from at least one of space and tab. "If the character is not space or tab" translated into logic is "if the character is not space AND the character is not tab".

Comment: DeMorgan's theorem: "remove it if it's a space or a tab" is the same as "keep it if it not a space **and** not a tab". That said, it's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the removespace(), problem is when you are taking the input.

It should be like this:

```
std::string line;
std::cout << "Enter the string with space/ tab to trim" << std::endl;
std::cin.getline (line);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used 
std::getline (std::cin,name); 
the input problem is resolved with this. But in the trim function even though im checking for ' ' & '\t' im not able to block the white spaces.

the removeSpace should be missing with something.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my function to get the expected answer as below

```
void removeSpace(const string &str)
{
    string tempStr;
    string p_str = str;
    int l_length = p_str.length();
    cout<<"Length of the String is : "<<l_length<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<l_length; i++)
    {
        if((p_str[i] == ' ') || (p_str[i] == '\t'))
        {
           continue;
        }
        else
        {
           cout<<p_str[i]<<endl;
           tempStr +=p_str[i]; //to add chars into tempstr
        }
    }
    cout<<tempStr<<'\n';
    return ;
}
```

but while I used if(p_str[i] != ' ' || p_str[i] != '\t') function was unable to discard spaces, can anybody tell me why this difference